# Flutter: Get Document Snapshot

Tags: dart, nosql, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I created a Listview builder passing `buildChatList` as my itembuilder but i noticed nothing is returned from the `buildChatList` when i HOT RESTART or Rebuild the app BUT actually returned the expected Data when i HOT RELOAD.
I don't understand why this is happening. I need help.

Below is my code so far.

```
buildChatList(BuildContext context, int index) {
    Map<String, dynamic> userDocumentt;
    print('INDEX $index COUNT $currentUserActiveChatsLength');
    String thisUserID = currentUserActiveChats[index];
    if (user.uid.hashCode <= thisUserID.hashCode) {
      groupChatId = '$_cuserID-$thisUserID';
    } else {
      groupChatId = '$thisUserID-$_cuserID';
    }
    Stream<QuerySnapshot> unreadMessages = Firestore.instance
        .collection('messages')
        .where("chatDetails.to", isEqualTo: user.uid)
        .where("chatDetails.sender", isEqualTo: thisUserID)
        .where("chatDetails.hasRead", isEqualTo: false)
        .snapshots();
    unreadMessages.listen((QuerySnapshot data) {
      unReadMessageLength = data.documents.length;
    });

    Stream<QuerySnapshot> lastMess = Firestore.instance
        .collection('messages')
        .where('groupChatId', isEqualTo: groupChatId)
        .orderBy('chatDetails.timestamp', descending: true)
        .limit(1)
        .snapshots();
    lastMess.listen((QuerySnapshot data) {
      List<DocumentSnapshot> userLastMess = data.documents;
      chatDetailSnapshotList = userLastMess.map((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
        return doc.data;
      }).toList();
    });
    Stream<DocumentSnapshot> userP = usersRef.document(thisUserID).snapshots();
    userP.listen((DocumentSnapshot snap) {
      userDocumentt = Map.from(snap.data);
      if (userDocumentt != null) {
        print('HELLOo $userDocumentt');
        myResult = new InkWell(
          highlightColor: Colors.grey[300],
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(
                new MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) =>
                        new Chat(chatWith: userDocumentt['id'])));
          },
          onLongPress: () {
            setState(() {
              modifyMode = true;
            });
          },
          child: new Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15.0),
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[

                    new Expanded(
                      child: new Container(
                        child: new Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            new Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 17.0, top: 5.0),
                              child: new Text(
                                userDocumentt['username'],
                                style: new TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            new Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 17.0, top: 7.0),
                              child: new Text(
                                chatDetailSnapshotList[0]["chatDetails"]
                                    ["content"],
                                maxLines: 1,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                style: new TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15.0,
                                  color: Colors.grey[800],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                new Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 72.0, top: 6.0, bottom: 6.0),
                  child: new Divider(
                    color: Colors.grey[300],
                    height: 10.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      } else {
        print('HELLLLOOO $userDocumentt');
        myResult = CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
    });
    return myResult;
  }
```

Comment: Are you fetching data (using streams) within a build() method? That would not work. You should setup all your listeners in the `initState()` method, and whenever they fire, use `setState()` to update the internal component state and then rebuild the UI.

Answer (score 7):

For Firestore It make sense to use 'StreamBuilder' for  real time updates, I am giving you a sample code I have for the same, Hope it helps.

```
StreamBuilder(
                 stream: Firestore.instance.collection("YourCollectionNAme").snapshots(),
                 builder: (BuildContext  context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot)
                 {
                   if (snapshot.hasData)
                   {
                   return new ListView.builder(
                     shrinkWrap: true,
                     itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                     padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                     itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      DocumentSnapshot ds = snapshot.data.documents[index];
                      return new Row(
                        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded (child:Text(ds["Field-of-collection"]) ),
                            Expanded (child:Text(ds["another-field"]) ),
                            Expanded (child:Text(ds["last-field"].toString()) ),


                          ],
                      );
      }
                   );
                 }
                 },
               )
```

I am using List view for my Firestore collection.

Comment: that works really well but what happens when I have to get a document based on a `uid` that I don't have ready yet?
I need to load the documents of the user is using the app so the authentication takes a bit until I can get this `uids`

Comment: did you try to use auth or login page before anything in the app?

Comment: no but because I don't need it. The user will log in... or not. If he doesn't want to, I need to wait until he logs in first to get his `uid`

Comment: in that case, use conditions like if uid present, load x stuff

Answer (score 0):

you will need to use `StreamBuilder` instead of normal ListView.builder().
check this [link](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html)

Updating data does not mean updating the view you need to rebuild this widget on every new record added, so when you HOT RELOAD the app you run setState() manually so it shows the update.

`StreamBuilder` will do this setState() for you on every new record

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not returning stream try this.

```
buildChatList(BuildContext context, int index) {
Map<String, dynamic> userDocumentt;
print('INDEX $index COUNT $currentUserActiveChatsLength');
String thisUserID = currentUserActiveChats[index];
if (user.uid.hashCode <= thisUserID.hashCode) {
  groupChatId = '$_cuserID-$thisUserID';
} else {
  groupChatId = '$thisUserID-$_cuserID';
}
Stream<QuerySnapshot> unreadMessages = Firestore.instance
    .collection('messages')
    .where("chatDetails.to", isEqualTo: user.uid)
    .where("chatDetails.sender", isEqualTo: thisUserID)
    .where("chatDetails.hasRead", isEqualTo: false)
    .snapshots();
unreadMessages.listen((QuerySnapshot data) {
  unReadMessageLength = data.documents.length;
});

Stream<QuerySnapshot> lastMess = Firestore.instance
    .collection('messages')
    .where('groupChatId', isEqualTo: groupChatId)
    .orderBy('chatDetails.timestamp', descending: true)
    .limit(1)
    .snapshots();
lastMess.listen((QuerySnapshot data) {
  List<DocumentSnapshot> userLastMess = data.documents;
  chatDetailSnapshotList = userLastMess.map((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return doc.data;
  }).toList();
});
myResult = Stream<DocumentSnapshot> userP = usersRef.document(thisUserID).snapshots();
userP.listen((DocumentSnapshot snap) {
  userDocumentt = Map.from(snap.data);
  if (userDocumentt != null) {
    print('HELLOo $userDocumentt');
    return InkWell(
      highlightColor: Colors.grey[300],
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(
            new MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) =>
                    new Chat(chatWith: userDocumentt['id'])));
      },
      onLongPress: () {
        setState(() {
          modifyMode = true;
        });
      },
      child: new Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15.0),
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Expanded(
                  child: new Container(
                    child: new Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 17.0, top: 5.0),
                          child: new Text(
                            userDocumentt['username'],
                            style: new TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        new Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 17.0, top: 7.0),
                          child: new Text(
                            chatDetailSnapshotList[0]["chatDetails"]
                                ["content"],
                            maxLines: 1,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            style: new TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15.0,
                              color: Colors.grey[800],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            new Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 72.0, top: 6.0, bottom: 6.0),
              child: new Divider(
                color: Colors.grey[300],
                height: 10.0,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  } else {

    //
    print('HELLLLOOO $userDocumentt');
    myResult = CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
});
return myResult;
```

}